# filling up remaining height

Tags: javascript, html, css, height

What is the preferred pattern for filling up the remaining height within the page.
for ex.

```
        <div class="container">
            <div class="fixed-height1"></div>
            <div class="remaining-height1">
               <div class="fixed-height2"></div>
               <div class="remaining-height2">
                   <div class="fixed-height3"></div>
                   <div class="remaining-height3">
                   </div> 
               </div> 
            </div> 
        </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Each wrapper element would have a `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` and you'd assign different `flex-grow` (weights) to the elements that you want to take the remaining space.